# ggplot labels for melted dataframes

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, melt

It's often the case I melt my dataframes to show multiple variables on one barplot. The goal is to create a `geom_bar` with one par for each variable, and **one** summary label for each bar.

For example, I'll do this:

```
mtcars$id<-rownames(mtcars)
tt<-melt(mtcars,id.vars = "id",measure.vars = c("cyl","vs","carb"))
ggplot(tt,aes(variable,value))+geom_bar(stat="identity")+
    geom_text(aes(label=value),color='blue')
```

The result is a barplot in which the label for each bar is repeated for each case (it seems):
[image: overlapping labels]

What I want to have is one label for each bar, like this:

[image]

A common solution is to create aggregated values to place on the graph, like this:

```
aggr<-tt %>% group_by(variable) %>% summarise(aggrLABEL=mean(value))

ggplot(tt,aes(variable,value))+geom_bar(stat="identity")+
    geom_text(aes(label=aggr$aggrLABEL),color='blue')
```

or

```
ggplot(tt,aes(variable,value))+geom_bar(stat="identity")+
    geom_text(label=dplyr::distinct(tt,value),color='blue')
```

However, these attempts result in errors, respectively:

For **solution 1:** Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (96): label, x, y

For **solution 2:** Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, aes_params, value = list(label = list( :   replacement element 1 is a matrix/data frame of 7 rows, need 96

So, what to do? Setting `geom_text` to `stat="identity"` does not help either.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking. Can you draw your expected output?

Comment: @Tung I added more details and an image!  Thanks for taking another look!

Comment: You should never use `$` inside `aes()`. Use the `data` argument for different data frames, e.g., `geom_text(data = aggr, aes(label = aggrLABEL),color='blue')`. It's this that causes the length mismatches - if you pull your x coords from `tt`, which has one length, and your labels from `aggr` which has a different length, it can mess things up.

Comment: @Gregor  Thanks!  I really appreciate the insight on the mechanics of all this.  However, if I use `ggplot(tt,aes(variable,value))+geom_bar(stat="identity")+
        geom_text(data=aggr, aes(label=~aggrLABEL),color='blue')` I still have an error `Don't know how to automatically  scale for object of type formula. Defaulting to continuous. Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'value' not found`

Comment: You added in a `~`. Don't do that. `~` makes it a formula. `aes()` expects bare, unquoted column names, not formulas.

Comment: @Gregor Without the t `~` the error says  "object 'value' not found"

Comment: Looks like you've got a working answer. I'm not trying to solve this in the comments, just prevent future problems that using `$` (or `~`) inside `aes()` will cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is create another dataframe with the summary values of your columns.  I would then refer to that dataframe in the `geom_text` line.  Like this:

```
library(tidyverse) # need this for the %>%

tt_summary <- tt %>%
 group_by(variable) %>%
 summarize(total = sum(value))

ggplot(tt, aes(variable, value)) +
geom_col() +
geom_text(data = tt_summary, aes(label = total, y = total), nudge_y = 1) # using nudge_y bc it looks better.
```

[image]